# want to change a .jsp file into .java

Tags: javascript, mysql, ajax

i am doing an autocomplete. it works nicely. but i wanted the second jsp file as .java file. i tried my best. i cant change it.please help me. the main problem is request.getparameter();

JSP Ajax Autocomplete box

autocomplete.jsp:

```
<%@page import="java.sql.*"%>    
<html>    
<head>    
<script type="text/javascript">    
function showData(value){     ``

xmlHttp=GetXmlHttpObject()
var url="auto.jsp";
url=url+"?name="+value;
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=stateChanged 
xmlHttp.open("GET",url,true)
xmlHttp.send(null)
}
function stateChanged() { 
if(xmlHttp.readyState==4 || xmlHttp.readyState=="complete"){ 
var showdata = xmlHttp.responseText; 
document.getElementById("mydiv").innerHTML= showdata;
} 
}
function GetXmlHttpObject(){
var xmlHttp=null;
try {
xmlHttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
catch (e) {
try  {
xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
}
catch (e)  {
 xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
 }
 }
return xmlHttp;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="employee">
<input  type="text" name="name" id="name" onkeyup="showData(this.value);"><br>
<div id="mydiv"></div>

</table>
</body>
</html>

auto.jsp (second jsp file)

<%@ page import="java.sql.*" %> 
<%

String name = request.getParameter("name").toString();
String buffer="<div>";  
 try{
       Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
       Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test",           "root", "root");
       Statement st=con.createStatement();
       ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("select * from data where name like '"+name+"%'");
 while(rs.next())
 {
 buffer=buffer+rs.getString("name")+"<br>";
 }
 buffer=buffer+"</div>";  
 response.getWriter().println(buffer);
 }
 catch (Exception e) {
 System.out.println(e);
 }
 %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a java file for search response while typing.

You can do this by creating a Servelet file.

Create a servelt for `/auto?name=value` and map using web.xml.